# Kotlinx Parcelize class extend

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, kotlin-android-extensions

I have two open classes `BaseNfcCard` and `SomeObjectNfcCard`.
Here `SomeObjectNfcCard` extends `BaseNfcCard` and `Parcelable`, also `BaseNfcCard` extends `Parcelable`.

When I pass `SomeObjectNfcCard` to another activity, I have data only from it and not from `BaseNfcCard`. Is this my code issue or lib?

```
@Parcelize
open class BaseCard(
        var cardId: String = "",
        var id: String = "",
        var type: Int = NfcFieldsHelper.UNDEFINED
) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
open class ObjectCard(
        var date: String = "",
        var objectState: Int = STATE_UNDEFINED,
        var managerId: String = "",
        var lastUpdate: String = "",

        var plombs: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
) : BaseCard(), Parcelable
```

Pass data to intent

```
private fun onCardParsed(result: ObjectCard) = startActivity(Intent(this,
        CardReadyActivity::class.java)
        .putExtra(CardReadyActivity.CARD_DATA, result))
```

Take data from intent

```
private lateinit var card: ObjectCard
card = intent?.extras?.getParcelable(CardReadyActivity.CARD_DATA)!!
```

Comment: what is `result`?

Comment: @TimCastelijns `result: ObjectCard` with populated fields

Answer (score 1):

This is actually documented in Parcelize:

> Note that only the primary constructor properties will be serialized.

https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/plugins/android-extensions/android-extensions-runtime/src/kotlinx/android/parcel/Parcelize.kt#L24

But judging by their [test cases](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/plugins/android-extensions/android-extensions-compiler/testData/parcel/box/nestedParcelable.kt#L24), composition should work:

```
@Parcelize
class ObjectCard(
        var baseCard: BaseCard,
        var date: String = "",
        var objectState: Int = 2,
        var managerId: String = "",
        var lastUpdate: String = "",
        var plombs: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
)
```

Comment: So only way it's to write parcable implementation code or do not use base class?

Comment: You should be also able to use composition. I updated by answer with an example.

Comment: Oh, I did not think it is better solution than write some code instread of use annotation.

Comment: Using composition instead of inheritance is not much more code. Please check the example above.

Comment: Yes, but with composition  I can not use java princeples of OOP

Comment: Composition is an OOP principle :)